# Apply a jquery function on multiple ID's

Tags: jquery

I need to allow users to input onlu numeric characters into two text boxes which are using different ID's.

```
        $('#signup-phone-number').keyup( function() {
            $(this).numeric();
        });
```

That code above is what I currently have. now i tried to change that to:

```
        $('#signup-phone-number', '#mobile-number').keyup( function() {
            $(this).numeric();
        });
```

The code above is not working. I just need to use Id's. no classes.

How I can do this please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use like

```
$('#signup-phone-number , #mobile-number').keyup( function() {
    $(this).numeric();
});
```

Even you can give all of them a `UNIQUE class` and use the event that you want on that class like

```
$('.common_class').keyup( function() {
    $(this).numeric();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the selectors within the same quotes:

```
$('#signup-phone-number, #mobile-number').keyup( function() {
    $(this).numeric();
});
```

Or alternatively add a class to both of those elements and use that instead, as it's a more semantic method.

Answer (score 1):

[multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

for multiple selectors use '`#signup-phone-number , #mobile-number'` not `'#signup-phone-number' , '#mobile-number'`

```
$('#signup-phone-number , #mobile-number').keyup( function() {
        $(this).numeric();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#segement1,#segement2,#segement3').hide()
      });
  </script>

    <div id="segement1"></div>
    <div id="segement2"></div>
    <div id="segement3"></div>
```

Comment: While your code may answer the question, it's often useful to include an explanation.